# ¿Etiquetas especiales de ASPX o HTML?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Estoy empezando diseñar sitios web con asp.net en c#, entonces desde el toolbox tengo los componentes gráficos como si estuviese diseñando una app de escritorio. Al arrastrar un boton, el código me muestra:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

También puedo poner botones con una etiqueta de html:

```
<button></button>
```

Existe alguna diferencia? cual me recomendarían usar?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La diferencia es que el `<asp:Button>` es un `Web Server Control`

[Controles de servidor ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb386416(v=vs.100).aspx)

en cambio si `<button>` o `<input type="button">` es solo html

Si defines `<button runat="server">` seria un Html Control, en este caso seria un [HtmlButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Controles HTML para páginas Web ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/t5d54cf8(v=vs.100).aspx)

Los web control y html control tienen eventos hacia el servidor, mientas que los html no los tienen, para esto seguro debas usar javascript o jquery enviando los datos por ajax con formato json

Si vas a programar usando `asp.net` usa los `Web Server Control` o sea `<asp:Button>` ya que contaras con los eventos.

Ahora si la idea es ir a `asp.net MVC` en ese caso si usarias controles de html.

Answer (score 3):

El botón de ASP `<asp:Button>` es un control del servidor que no sólo está disponible en el lado del cliente, sino al que puedes acceder desde el lado del servidor usando su ID. En cambio un `<button>` es un control HTML que muestra un botón cuyo ámbito está limitado al lado del cliente.

Otra diferencia es que `<asp:Button>` hace que se mande el formulario con un POST cada vez que se hace click en él (*postback*), algo que no ocurre cuando se usa `<button>`.

La recomendación sobre cuál de ellos usar dependerá de para qué quieras usarlos. Si quieres el botón sólo para hacer algún tipo de validación/lógica en el lado del cliente, usa `<button>`; si quieres el botón para hacer alguna operación en el lado del servidor, usa `<asp:Button>`.